# String CONSTRAINT_ERROR length check failed

Tags: string, ada, constraintexception

I have an array that holds strings of a maximum of 20 characters:

```
subtype c_string is string(1..20);
type string_array is array (natural range 1..100) of c_string;
```

When I try to assign a string to a position of string_array, I get the following error if the string is not exactly 20 characters long:

> > raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : (...) length check failed

This is the line of code that causes the problem:

```
str_a: string_array;
(....)
str_a(n) := "stringToAssign"        --Causes error
```

What would the best way to avoid this be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `c_string` can’t hold a *maximum* of 20 characters; it holds *exactly* 20 characters, hence the CE.

You could use [`Ada.Strings.Bounded`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-4.html) if it’s important to have an upper limit, or [`Ada.Strings.Unbounded`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html) if you don’t actually care.

In the *bounded* case, that’d be something like

```
package B_Strings is new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length (Max => 20);
type String_Array is array (1 .. 200) of B_Strings.Bounded_String;
```

and then

```
Str_A : String_Array;
Str_A (N) := B_Strings.To_Bounded_String (“stringToAssign”);
```

There’s more in the [Ada Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Strings).

Comment: Thank you. How would I convert a bounded_string back to a normal string?

Comment: I think I have the answer: B_Strings.To_String(bounded_string_var). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I recommend lecture of reference manual - annex A describes standard library in details.

Comment: `To_String()` is indeed the way to convert a bounded string to a plain `String`.